# What to call someone who cries out "wow" all the time?

Tags: word-request, vocabulary, expressions

What to call someone who (silently, but loud enough that the talking person hears it) cries out "wow" (throughout another person's monologue) all the time as an expression of delight or admiration (?) The talking person is someone of authority.

Comment: Well, this person must be really zealous to be so excited all the time.

Comment: Is that person really surprised or just falsely praising?

Comment: @snailplane - I was thinking about a lickspittle, but wasn't sure actually.

Comment: @Maulik - Perhaps it seemed a bit artificial, because it was done so consistantly.

Comment: @snailplane Yess...that's it! Obsequious or flatterer. I love these terms!

Comment: If it's annoyingly repetitious, and sounds somewhat immature, I might say this person ***talks like a Valley Girl***. If you, like, Google the expression `talks like a Valley Girl`, you'll find all sorts of background information and news on *Valleyspeak*, including – OMG! – research by [linguists](http://www.washingtonpost.com/national/health-science/linguists-explain-how-to-tell-statements-from-questions-in-valley-girl-talk/2013/12/05/1bc64e4c-5cf6-11e3-95c2-13623eb2b0e1_story.html).

Comment: @J.R. - But if the person is a guy? Can you still say that? This person doesn't use inappropriate language, though, such as OMG.

Comment: @user76935 - It wouldn't be a compliment, but, yes, you could still say it. (I'd have to hear the "wows" myself to see if my suggestion would be a good fit.) As the article I linked to says: _"The dialect is usually associated with female speakers — hence the name — but the research, which Ritchart is presenting at a meeting of the Acoustical Society of America in San Francisco on Thursday, suggests that uptalk is not limited to women. The differences in pitch were less exaggerated and less frequent with the men in the study, but they used them, too."_ Gnarly, dude.

Comment: I was going to answer *follower* or *enthusiast*, but then I saw *lickspittle*, so I'm not sure now. In any case, I left the two words in hope that they might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 2):

They sound like they are a [sycophant](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sycophant).

Some slang terms:

They could also be a *brown-nose* / *brown-noser*. That's pretty vulgar. Their nose is brown because it is firmly wedged in someone else's ass crack.

Or they could be a *suck-up*. They are *sucking up*. That's also vulgar.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest 'wowser', but that Australian English word already means about the complete opposite (more information [here](http://andc.anu.edu.au/australian-words/meanings-origins?field_alphabet_value=281) and scroll down a bit).

Comment: Obviously, a wowser needs wowsees. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

An adjective that might fit is *infatuated*.

Answer (score -1):

Considering your response to my comment, the context seems of a person who unnecessarily praises (or simply agrees) with exclamation or surprise to the person who's an authority.

I'm **not sure there's a term** that represents a person calling out *wow* every time (and in this case, you may simply go with your own version) **but** there's a good term for a person who does it just to praise falsely. This often refers to a person who falsely praises his/her boss by simply agreeing to whatever the boss says.

**One of the terms** is *flatterer*

> [flatterer](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/FLATTERER) - A person who uses [flattery](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/FLATTERY)

The other similar terms include *[obsequious](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=obsequious)* and *[adulator](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/ADULATOR)*.

I consider that in this context, *wow* is an expression of surprised admiration.